# How to create a function in nltk to generate aspect of a verb in a sentence?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

For example, if the following sentence is given `They have been swimming for more than an hour` the function should return perfect progressive.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate your question a little more? What have you done so far?

Comment: Corrected grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little old library but it will be a good intro for you.

https://www.nodebox.net/code/index.php/Linguistics

```
print en.verb.present_participle("be")
>>> being

print en.verb.present("gave")
print en.verb.present("gave", person=3, negate=False)
>>> give
>>> gives

print en.verb.tense("was")
>>> 1st singular past
```

Comment: I want aspect of the sentence(actually aspect of verb) i.e whether the verb is simple,perfect,progressive or perfect progressive

Comment: Added the exact method.